# SwiftData stores object without insert

Tags: ios, swift, swift-data

When I instantiate a model and set a relationship to a persistent object, the model is stored in the container without calling `insert` on it.

Given

```
@Model
final class Order {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var orderId: String
    
    var items: [Item] = []
    
    init(orderId: String) {
        self.orderId = orderId
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var timestamp: Date
    
    var order: Order?
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

I create a `Item`

```
let item = Item(timestamp: Date())
// here the order is not stored
item.order = sharedModelContainer.mainContext.anOrder
// here after setting the relationship to an existing order the item is stored
```

`anOrder` is just

```
extension ModelContext {
    var anOrder: Order? {
        let desc = FetchDescriptor(predicate: #Predicate<Order> { order in true })
        let orders = try! fetch(desc)
        return orders.first
    }
}
```

No `insert` is called on any context.

Disabling auto-save is not a solution. My question is why it is saved without inserting it.

Is it supposed to be like that? Is it desirable?

Comment: This is an interesting find that I hadn't realised before. _"...why it is saved without inserting it"_, this isn't exactly true is it, it is inserted for us by the framework indirectly and most likely to either make it easy for us and/or to avoid a bad state where one end of a relationship is in a context while the other isn't. _"Is it supposed to be like that?"_, I don't know but I believe so and I think it could simplify things. _"Is it desirable?"_, it's a bit confusing when it's not documented but I think it can be helpful. But this is only my guesses and opinions.